# issue with media query and screen resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, mpmediaquery

I have written my media queries for almost all devices that exist, and they're pretty good in all the latest mobile devices and also on the various web-based simulators, device wise. For a few devices like iPhone 5s and Samsung Galaxy Trend, however, a few elements are appearing a bit small in size. Meanwhile, the problem is not there for a few devices that have the same document width as the Trend and the 5s. Here are my media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1051px) and (max-width:1111px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 65%;
    }
        .logo img {
        left: -13%;
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1026px) and (max-width:1050px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1025px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:980px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:853px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:736px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:667px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:603px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:568px) 
{
    .logo 
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo img 
    {
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: unset;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your media queries please so that we can know what you have tried?

Comment: please check I edited my post and added queries